# Django summernote text editor when edit the bullet point or number it's not showing on Django template?

Tags: django, django-forms, summernote

SummerNote editor bullet point and number not showing on Django Template here my config
setting.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
        'web.apps.WebConfig',
        'django_summernote',
    ]
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
```

here url.py settings

```
path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
```

admin.py settings

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Navmenu, NavSubmenu, WebPage, WebUrl, Seo,NewLatter, Project
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin
class ProjectAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','sort_title','slug','create_by','create_at','update_at','status')
    summernote_fields = ('desc')
admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

view.py settings

```
def Projects_Details(request,slug):
    tags = Seo.objects.filter(pages_title__name = "Project-Details").first()

    pro_de = Project.objects.filter(slug = slug).first()
    context = {
        'tags':tags,
        'pro_de':pro_de,
    }
    return render(request,'web/project_detail.html', context)
```

templates

```
{{pro_de.desc | safe}}
```

here editor pic.
[image]

and here template output pic.
[image]